# Mediaplayer can't stream video format

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-videoview

I am trying to find a library that can stream .mpga video file over internet in my app. I've tried the android video lib, Sony's multimedia lib but all fail to stream. Any ideas? here's a screen shot from vlc codec info..

[image: VLC clipping]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mpeg 2 is a poor choice for video delivery over the internet. You can probably add a software decoder to your application, but it would take a lot of power to run on a mobile device and would be a lot of work to implement. It would be much better to use a format that device can already play such as AVC. It would be a lower bitrate, saving bandwidth, and be able to take advantage of the accelerated decoders on mobile (and non mobile) platforms. Long story short - Convert the video on the server side to something your targeted platform CAN play.